# visual studio 2017 “ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)” template missing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I installed visual studio 2017 and i don't see the 
ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core) template.

I already installed .net core SDK and restart my pc and nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its under File >  New> Project> Web> Asp.Net Core WEb Applications

Comment: hey, when I open angular 4 project it looks like it change or update version. I see app.module.server.ts, app.module.shared.ts. actually it was not before when i open regular angular project